# how to solve java heap space out of memory issue in Solr

Tags: asp.net, solr

I am using Apache Solr version 4.6.0. I am getting out of memory exception when querying for name field. I am not very familiar with solr. I use it to search name . the core contains about 47M names. If anybody has encountered similar error, please share how you solved it. the error message is :

```html
null:java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.sendError(SolrDispatchFilter.java:724)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:434)
 at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:197)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1419)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:455)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:137)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:557)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:231)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1075)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:384)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1009)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:154)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:368)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:489)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handleRequest(BlockingHttpConnection.java:53)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:942)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1004)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:640)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.BlockingHttpConnection.handle(BlockingHttpConnection.java:72)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.server.bio.SocketConnector$ConnectorEndPoint.run(SocketConnector.java:264)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
 at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

Comment: just want to ask one thing,do you get the error while doing a full import also.

Answer (score 1):

> java ... -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m ...

Above allocate 1GB memory of heap size, if you have more physical memory then use it.

---

`-Xms` used for initial memory allocation pool.

`-Xmx` used for maximum memory allocation pool.

And recommended to set same value.

---

If still not fixed, then its time to search for memory leaks in your application.

> read more about -X settings by run the command `java -X`

And remember to check your Java Virtual Machine version. If 32-bit or 64-bit version is installed. While the (theoretical) maximum heap size on the 32-bit is 4 GB and for 64-bit is 2^64 (which is looots of GB).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. But can we be sure that -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m is sufficient. the size of the core is seen as 2.38 GB in the admin screen

Comment: how much RAM do your hardware run with? try with higher values in your X arguments. And remember to check your JVM version, if 32bit or 64bit used. While maximum heap size on 32-VM is 4GB and for 64-VM its 2^64.

Comment: the server has 16 GB RAM, an asp application which is the core application is in the same server. The database itself uses around 12GB of RAM.

Comment: Do you have access to more hardware? I would try to run db on one machine and the application on another, and dedicate full power to db and application from each desktop/server hardware. Also check your application if there is any flaws/memory leaks. I dont know your application...

Comment: no i dont have access to more hardware. In my test system which has only 4GB RAM, I simualted a similar scenario. But the error message i am getting in my test machine is ** null:org.eclipse.jetty.io.EofException ** . Is this error related to the one I have posted above in my question